# Eclipse says my class cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse is saying my class cannot be resolved. I would like to know why it is doing this, and how I can fix it.

The error occurs in line 7. Here is my code:

[image]

Here is the class I'm attempting to use in the condition of the while loop:

[image]

Comment: Is `IntegerTester` in the same package?

Comment: Also, I don't think your `IsInt` method will work reliably.

Comment: Import the class if it's not in the same pkg

Comment: To me, you chose a odd way to test if the number is int or not

Comment: @Daniel Can't we tell from looking at it that they're both in the default package?

Comment: @ChrisMartin How can you tell? I haven't used Eclipse in years.

Comment: @Daniel There's no `package` statement.

Comment: Save the file as sometimes Eclipse doesn't work stuff out until that is done.

Comment: @KickButtowski I saw that one and it didn't seem to have solutions I was looking for. It was saying make the method static and mine already was so I determined it was a different problem.

Comment: @Daniel I just saved it into the same package. It has fixed my problem, thank you for that. Do you know how I could improve my integer tester?

Comment: @Dunka If you're changing the subject, please open a new question. And next time, include the code rather than a screenshot.

Comment: @ChrisMartin will do. Is there a tutorial on how to use the code formatting on this website?

Comment: @Dunka Paste your code, highlight it, and press ctrl+k. That will indent it so it will be treated as a code block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IntegerTester` must be in the same package as `PrimeNumberProgram`, otherwise you cannot access one from the other without `import`ing.